# Encoder to Arduino connection (22A ERCB)

Tags: arduino, encoder

I have the following encoder below that I would like to connect to an Arduino.
[image]

I am trying to figure out how to connect the 3 wires.  The 2 grey wires I assume are the signal pins as usual and should be connected to interrupt pins on the arduino? (correct me if I'm wrong) but I'm not sure where to connect the red wire.  Most tutorial I read tells me to connect it to GND but on the data sheet it says

```
Analog output - Current / voltage and PWM output
```

Datasheet:
http://www.rotacol.info/22aercb.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a potentiometer not encoder.  The red wire takes 5v input and other 2 wires are for GND and analog input.